# How to get character entered on Keydown Event in WPF C#

Tags: character, arabic, keydown

i'm using wpf c# in visual studio
i want to prevent user can enter Arabic character , Just Persian Character

like when user entered this value on keyboard → "ي"  change it to "ی"

my means something like this :
when user press button to type "A" on keyboard i want to change this character, first check if is "A" change to "B"

i did it in Windows Form Application , but that code does not work in WPF

My Code in Windows From :

```
if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "ي")
            {
                e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar("ی");
            }
```

My Code in WPF :

```
 if (e.Key.ToString() == "ي")
    {
         e.Key.ToString("ی");
     }
```

These codes not working in WPF

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit different in WPF.

This works using a english keyboard. Don't know if it will work with Arabic, as the rules might be a little different for inserting characters.

You can try handling the **PreviewTextInput** event of the TextBox.

**XAML**:

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="TextBox_OnTextInput" ...
```

**Code**:

```
        private void TextBox_OnTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            var box = (sender as TextBox);
            var text = box.Text;
            var caret = box.CaretIndex;

            if (e.TextComposition.Text == "ي")
            {
                var newValue = "ی";

                //Update the TextBox' text..
                box.Text = text.Insert(caret, newValue);
                //..move the caret accordingly..
                box.CaretIndex = caret + newValue.Length;
                //..and make sure the keystroke isn't handled again by the TextBox itself:
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but its getting button name not value

i tried this code

see this link : https://img.techpowerup.org/201006/3.png


please check my problem not solved !

Comment: I've updated the answer to use TextInput event. To test this I enable Arabic keyboard and pressed D in the text box.

Note that this isn't perfect - it changes how the textbox behaves when inserting/ modifying text, so it might cause some problems when someone selects some text and presses a key to overwrite the text, it will not work.  

To fix this you will now need to check the selected text.

This is just to answer your main question.

Comment: Thank you very much engineer but how can i do it On TextChange Event  That Code Not accepting this "TextComposition" on the textchange event